# Duplicate Key Exception from Mongo DB does not gets caught

Tags: spring-data-mongodb-reactive

Trying to insert duplicate documents in mongo db with help of mongo repository.

Snippet example:
`try{ //insertion of duplicate doc in mongo db } catch(org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException e){ // syso for something else for sake of this example }`

**I can see the exception getting thrown in console like errorMsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection**

**But in code its not coming to catch block at all.**

Why this exception cannot be caught in catch block?

Tried catching this exception with all the below exception instances:
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException,
com.mongodb.MongoWriteException,
Exception.

Since the exception is getting thrown and its evident from the logs it should be caught in catch block.

Comment: have you tried catching it with catch(Exception e) block ? The problem could be occuring because the exception that occured and the exception you are handling are of different types. Catch it with the Exception e , and check its type while debugging or logging.

Comment: yes I tried Exception e as well in catch block. But strangely that is also not catching it.